# Ui-Router Create New Controller In View

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Given that I am going to the following state:

```
  $stateProvider.state('applicant', {
  url: "/admin/applicants/:name",
  templateProvider: function($http, $stateParams) {
  return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://example.com/applicant',
    params: {
      request: $stateParams.name,
    }
  }).then(function successCallback(html) {
    return html.data;
  });
},
  controller: 'SendToCtrl'
});
```

With the view that is being returned by `$http` looking like this:

```
<script>
app.controller('ChildController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.applicant = <?php echo $applicant ?>;
}]);
</script>
    <div class="row" ng-controller="ChildController">
<div class="col-md-12">
{{applicant.State}}
</div>
</div>
```

I get a **Argument 'ChildController' is not a function** error. I read that in the regular `ng-view` calling a new controller like this is not supported, but couldn't find an answer for `ui-router`. What would be the proper way to do templating then if I need the template to display data that is only there once the view is served?

Comment: I would start with something simpler in your ChildController: remove the php scripting and just put console.log('controller active'); 
Also, where is "app" in app.controller being defined? This might be a problem as well.

Comment: @TSmith Even after purging ChildController of its php content I still get the same error. Also app is defined earlier in the page.

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't generate the controller from within the view like I wanted, so instead I used the controller generated by the state and attached the php variable to the view, then picked it back up again from said set controller, like so:

State Definition:

```
$stateProvider.state('applicant', {
      url: "/admin/applicants/:name",
      templateProvider: function($http, $stateParams) {
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://example.com/applicant',
        params: {
          request: $stateParams.name,
        }
      }).then(function successCallback(html) {
        return html.data;
      });
    },
      controller: 'SendToCtrl'
    });
```

View:

```
<?php
$applicant = str_replace('"', "'", $applicant);
?>
<div class="row">
<div id="fetchMe" class="col-md-12">
</div>
</div>
<script>
applicant = <?php echo $applicant ?>;
$('#fetchMe').data('key',applicant);
</script>
```

SendToCtrl:

```
app.controller('SendToCtrl', ["$scope", "$stateParams", "$state", function($scope, $stateParams, $state) {

    console.log($stateParams);
    $scope.applicant = $("#fetchMe").data('key');
    console.log($scope.applicant);
}]);
```

:)